# How to destructure dynamic when using MEL ILogger<T> as a facade?

Tags: asp.net-core, logging, .net-core, serilog

I'm implementing some logging methods in an application, and I need to pass dynamic (i.e. JSON) values as data.

Now, I've found Desctructurama extension for Serilog, and it works well if I inject the logger dependency as Serilog's own ILogger type. However, if I inject `Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ILogger<T>`, it doesn't.

The thing is Serilog appears to have the support of the asp.net core logging facade since it's accepting the message template and the values passed alright. It is for sure using the logger configuration done in Startup class. It even does at least some destructuring for wHat I see, but it ignores Destructurama's JsonNetTypes extension. You call Serilog's `ILogger.Error` -> correct destructuring, you call MS's `ILogger<T>.LogError` -> incorrect destructuring. The messages end up in the samE sinks, so the calls are clearLy passed to the same logger instance underneath. The message temPlate and the values are the same, I'm just calling both interfaces at the saMe time for the test, so the configuration is OK.

Just injecting Serilog.ILogger is contradicting the client's inner sense of beauty so I guess I'm stuck with `ILogger<T>` instEad.

Edit:
It looks like `ILogger<T>` is ignoring the destructuring pipeline of Serilog. For example I've tried to add this to exclude the possibility it's Desctructurama's fault:

```
.Destructure.ByTransforming<Dictionary<Guid, string[]>>(dic => new { Noim = "ABCDEFG" })
```

And the logging:

```
var dic = new Dictionary<Guid, string[]>();
_logger.LogError("{@dic}", dic);
_serilog.Error("{@dic}", dic);
```

The result is the `_serilog` call produces the value of `fields.dic.Noim =  ABCDEFG`, while the `_logger` (which is `ILogger<T>`) call just results in `fields.dic = nothing`.

Comment: How are you configuring the logging pipeline in the application? `AddSerilog()`, or `UseSerilog()`?

Comment: @NicholasBlumhardt it uses loggerFactory.AddSerilog(); in startup.

Comment: `UseSerilog()` is often a better bet, see e.g. [setup in ASP.NET Core 2.x](https://nblumhardt.com/2017/08/use-serilog/) and [in 3.x](https://nblumhardt.com/2019/10/serilog-in-aspnetcore-3/)